# Format for an animated logo in mobile, preferably in revolution slider

Tags: wordpress, animation, revolution-slider

I would like an animated logo in the banner of my wordpress site, preferably in Revolution Slider. The catch is that I want it to work in mobile too so it can't be in video format. I can make a simple animation with Revolution slider (fade, bounce etc.), but if I want it more complex, what format would work in mobile? Would it be animated gif?

Comment: Animated GIF will work on mobile.  Just make sure it's not something too annoying or distracting, or it will discourage users from using your site at all.  You can definitely check out [ux.se] for something on that. Either way, go for a higher frame rate to make it more smooth.

Comment: You should also take into consideration that having it in the header of every page will increase load time (possibly by a lot if the image is large and/or the animation is long)